# how can I configure some settings, from nerd commenter (lazyvim)

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I am a new user of neovim, and I install the plugin nerd commenter. I am using lazy vim and need to add this config:
 `let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = { 'gdscript': { 'left': '#', 'leftAlt': '', 'rightAlt': '', 'right': '' } }`

but i dont know where, this is my nvim dir:

[nvim dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sgaO.png)

I already tried to put it in the init.lua file, but I found some errors